# How do I install Ubuntu in VMware?

Tags: system-installation, virtualization, vmware

I am using Windows 8 and want to install Ubuntu in virtual environment.

How do I install Ubuntu in VMware?

Answer (score 2):

To install Ubuntu in VMware:

1. Download VMware from [here](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_workstation/6_0) and Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download).
2. They have some different version of Workstations. Pick one of each which fits for your computer.
3. Double click on the VMware software application and run it.
4. Click <kbd>Next</kbd> to install.
5. Keep pressing <kbd>Next</kbd> until you see `finish`and then click <kbd>finish</kbd>.
6. After that, double click on the Icon which is named VMware Workstation is located on the desktop. Clicking on File --> New --> Virtual Machine…  then choose Typical --> Next.
7. If you have software in DVD which contained software that you want to create, choose Install disc. Otherwise, Choosing the Installer Disc image file (ISO) software application with extension ISO.
8. Keep pressing “Next” to continue.
9. Setting maximum disk size (GB) as 8 and choose the option “Store virtual disk as a single file”, then hit "Next"
10. Enter username and password in Ubuntu.
11. Keep pressing "Next" until you see finish then hit <kbd>Finish</kbd>
12. It will automatically reboot , next, it will run an Ubuntu application as well (the one input "Ubuntu.ISO" above step).
13. The installing screen will appear and run as the picture.
14. After finish running the installation, restart now

[Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-VMware-and-Use-VMware-to-Install-Ubuntu)

Comment: If solved mark(tick) this as answer!@Amit

Comment: Note that by default this will give you a US keyboard.  If you want any other keyboard, you'll have to change it after installation.