# How to start Ubuntu as boot, without installing?

Tags: windows-10

**Please help me!
Can somebody say to me how to start Ubuntu on my Windows 10 without installing Ubuntu... I think how to strat Ubuntu as boot? Or just tell me Can i start like this...**

Answer (score 4):

You can make a Ubuntu USB Installer, and then when the installation program runs just click on "Try ubuntu without install"...this is a guest session...all  you do will be lost when you start the computer again. But you can try everything Ubuntu offers or just take a look what Ubuntu is o looks like. You can install windows and ubuntu together if you want too.

If you dont know how to make a USB installer you can use Rufus program, its free and easy to use...and you can download the ISO from the ubuntu.com page.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your description *without installing Ubuntu* is a bit ambiguous. Following are the ways that might help you out:

1. Install [Virtual Box/VMware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668860/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-vmware), and have Ubuntu as a virtual OS in it. You can just start and stop it as and when you need.
2. You can create [USB-installer-stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
3. If you just want to a taste of Ubuntu and not have long-term work plans, insert Ubuntu installation disk and instead of choosing full installation, go for *Try Ubuntu*